# Node- / ExpressJS - Could not obtain grant code: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, keycloak

I'm building a WebApp with Node- & ExpressJS. Currently I'm trying to connect my app to our company's Keycloak with the keycloak-connect module. I configured it as mentioned in different tutorials and it works (atleast mostly).

When I connect to my WebApp, I receive the keycloak login screen and the login procedure is successful (session created on keycloak). After the login procedure and the redirect I receive an "Access denied" error and in the logs "Could not obtain grant code: unable to get local issuer certificate".

*WebApp runs on port 443 with valid certificates*

---

I've googled everything I could and tried following solutions:

**-- Disable rejecting unauthorized TLS --**

Disabled TLS Rejection for unauthorized certificates with the node envorinment variable:

- process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

Works but isn't very secure...
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xknnj.png).

**-- Add an extra CA certificate --**

Installed dotenv module and set following env variable in .env file:

- NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem' (& ca-bundle.crt)

Included it in app.js with "require('dotenv').config();", doesn't work... Also tried to set it as a system environment variable with export.

---

It stands behind a proxy but I also configured express to trust all proxies with "app.set('trust proxy', true);".

---

**-- Versions --**

Node - v16.13.1

Express - ~4.16.1

Keycloak-connect - ^16.1.1

---

I've seen this problem on many different pages and they're mostly not fully resolved... Would be nice to find a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Yannic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found a solution and it works perfectly!

This [comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4175#issuecomment-238211757) on a GitHub issue describes, how to send ca files with the HTTPS server from NodeJS.

---

You can enter your ca files / bundles in an array:

```
const trustedCa = [
    '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt',
    '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem'
];
```

Then read them with fileSync and set them as the globalAgent.options.ca option for the HTTPS server:

```
https.globalAgent.options.ca = [];
for (const ca of trustedCa) {
    https.globalAgent.options.ca.push(fs.readFileSync(ca));
}
```

---

And that's all that needs to be done! Now I can login via Keycloak and it successfully redirects me to my WebApp without any errors.

Hopefully this helps.

Yannic